# how to add programmatically drop down menu in navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

can anyone tell.  how to create drop down menu in iPhone,and i want add drop down menu  in navigateion bar  (my concept is sorting(filter) so i want three buttons in menu name,title,description .....)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UIPopoverController` for iPhone.

It's available [here](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover).

In the popover you can add a `UIPickerView` and there's the drop-down.
Basically , on iPhone you can use a `UITableView` or `UIPickerView` to simulate a drop down.
And to place it in a nice container you can use the above mentioned popover.

Comment: No, you can't unfortunately. `UIPopoverController` is iPad-exclusive. See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes , `UIPopoverController ` is for iPad only but I've put a link there to a custom `UIPopoverController` that's for iPhone too.

Comment: my comment was meant to go on the other answer. Sorry about that. Thanks for the tip, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a component in `iOS`, so you need to create it by yourself.
You can do that by adding a `UIView` under your button, and animate it.
Something like...

```
 [self.view addSubview:myMenu];
[myMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(100,30,150,0)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animation:^{
    [myMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(100,30,150,200)];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //on Drop down button click  
 -(IBAction)btnDropdownPressed:(id)sender{
if (![popoverController isPopoverVisible]) 
{
  PopOverViewController *attShow=[[PopOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PopOverViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"arrFiles==%@",arrFiles);

    attShow.arrFiles=arrFiles;
  {
    popoverController=[[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:attShow] retain];
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(500,250)];

    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 500, 30) inView:btnMore permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

}else {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   }

}
```

PopOverViewController.h

```
  {
IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
NSArray *arrFiles;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *arrFiles;
```

PopOverViewController.m

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
return [self.arrFiles count];
  }

 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
return 40;
   }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text=[self.arrFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f];
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;
}
```